# jQuery - best way to toggle text in a click function

Tags: jquery

I have a click function that looks like this:

```
jQuery('#phy-more').click(function() {
            // slideToggle slides open and closes address and phone number
    jQuery('.views-field-field-satellite-address').slideToggle();
    jQuery('.views-field-field-satellite-phone').slideToggle();
            // text displays "More" on page load and i want it to change to less
                // when the address and phone display then back to more when hidden
    jQuery('#phy-more').text('LESS');
});
```

As you can see in my commented out code, as i have it right now, the text will just change to `LESS` when clicked. what would be the best way of toggling it to Show `More` on load (which is its default) and then toggle `LESS` and `More`?

I am fairly new to using jQuery and any help would be much appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ternary operator` by means of `.is()` function and `:visible` selector to achieve what you want

Try,

```
jQuery('#phy-more')
.text((jQuery('.views-field-field-satellite-address').is(':visible'))?'LESS':'MORE');
```

Comment: That's not a good idea... When fast clicking on the div, it will show the wrong text.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Can we put this snippet in call back of anyone of that animation.? :)

Comment: Hmmm I don't know exactly how jQuery will react, but will probably work. You should try!

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy - That snippet did not seem to work for me. still no change on the second click.

Comment: @scapegoat17 Just try to add this in a call back of any one of that animation

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy - I am afraid I dont understand. I am sorry.

Comment: @scapegoat17 like, jQuery('.views-field-field-satellite-phone').slideToggle(400,function(){ //put the code here });

Answer (score 0):

I've made a little plugin sometime ago, but isn't foolproof. You can try it out!

Insert that in your code:

```
if(!$.fn.toggleText){
$.fn.toggleText = function(text1, text2){
    var objText = {};
    objText[text1] = text2;
    objText[text2] = text1;
    return this.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.text(objText[$.trim($this.text())]);
    })
}
}
```

Then do :

```
jQuery('#phy-more').toggleText('LESS', 'MORE');
```